# encoding password in spring-integration or xd

Tags: spring-integration, spring-xd

I want to encode my acccessKey and secretKey in options during stream definition is there any utility for the same in xd or integration?I want to encode the key in options

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
       xmlns:int-aws="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/aws"
       xmlns:int-file="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file/spring-integration-file.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/aws http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/aws/spring-integration-aws-1.0.xsd">

    <int:poller fixed-delay="${fixedDelay}" default="true"/>

    <bean id="credentials" class="org.springframework.integration.aws.core.BasicAWSCredentials">
        <property name="accessKey" value="${accessKey}"/>
        <property name="secretKey" value="${secretKey}"/>
    </bean>


    <!-- aws-endpoint="https://s3.amazonaws.com"  proxyHost="proxy.kdc.capitalone.com" proxyPort="8099"-->
    <bean id="clientConfiguration" class="com.amazonaws.ClientConfiguration">
        <property name="proxyHost" value="${proxyHost}"/>
        <property name="proxyPort" value="${proxyPort}"/>
    <property name="preemptiveBasicProxyAuth" value="false"/> 
    </bean>

    <bean id="s3Operations" class="org.springframework.integration.aws.s3.core.CustomC1AmazonS3Operations">
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="credentials"/>
        <constructor-arg index="1" ref="clientConfiguration"/>
        <property name="awsEndpoint" value="s3.amazonaws.com"/>
        <property name="temporaryDirectory" value="${temporaryDirectory}"/>
        <property name="awsSecurityKey"  value="${awsSecurityKey}"/>
    </bean>



    <!-- aws-endpoint="https://s3.amazonaws.com"  -->
    <int-aws:s3-inbound-channel-adapter aws-endpoint="s3.amazonaws.com"
                                        bucket="${bucket}"
                                        s3-operations="s3Operations"
                                        credentials-ref="credentials"
                                        file-name-wildcard="${fileNameWildcard}"
                                        remote-directory="${remoteDirectory}"
                                        channel="splitChannel"
                                        local-directory="${localDirectory}"
                                        accept-sub-folders="false"
                                        delete-source-files="true"
                                        archive-bucket="${archiveBucket}"
                                        archive-directory="${archiveDirectory}">
    </int-aws:s3-inbound-channel-adapter>




    <int-file:splitter input-channel="splitChannel" output-channel="output" markers="true">


    </int-file:splitter>


    <int:channel id="output"/>
```

stream definations

```
module upload --file   aws.jar  --name aws-s3-options --type source

stream create feedTest29 --definition "aws-s3-options  --accessKey=kkkk --secretKey=yyyy--temporaryDirectory=/tmp/output --awsSecurityKey=zzzz --bucket=test --fileNameWildcard=*.*  --localDirectory=/tmp/MM/  | log" --deploy
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it isn't possible yet as out-of-the-box feature: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-10666.

But I'd consider something like [Spring Crypto Utils](http://springcryptoutils.com/) to use for such kind of task. It may looks like:

```
<crypt:b64SymmetricCiphererWithStaticKey id="decrypter" 
                             key="Rs3xEA16I52XJpsWwkw4GrB8l6FiVGK/"
                             initializationVector="AQIDBAUGAQI="
                             mode="DECRYPT"/>
```

Of course, you can choose any other way to decript the encoded keys.

Then usage may look like:

```
<property name="awsSecurityKey" value="#{decrypter.encrypt('${awsSecurityKey}')}"/>
```